# Ubuntu 18.04 dual display - menus not working on primary display

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, menu, context-menu

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a lenovo laptop with a 1920 x 1080 display. I have extended the desktop to my AOC 28" monitor (3840 x 2160).

Any context menus on the primary display appear squashed at the top of the screen, no matter where the menu should be appearing, and appear like spin controls, making them almost impossible to use. The same is true of most (but not all) applications. Here is a screen shot of me trying to drop down the terminal menu from a terminal window.
[Terminal menu squashed at top of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7f5r.png).

It all works fine if I disconnect the monitor, and I've discovered that the menus do actually work on the external display, so I can work around it. It's just pretty irritating.

Any ideas how to fix it? What more info do I need to provide?

Comment: i am experiencing the same issue. display 2 is above the main laptop display.

if i make display 2 (which is above the laptop display 1) into the primary display then it seems to be fine

Comment: Same issue here with same monitor arrangement, external is Samsung 49" ultrawide. Tooltips exhibit the same behaviour. Trying out the workaround now.

Comment: I had a similar problem where a context menu opened on my second monitor would appear at the edge of my main monitor. Resetting the NVIDIA X Server settings to default fixed this for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/918054/969758